# Python list elements in multiple SQL queries in the Like operator

Tags: python, sql, list, iteration

I am trying to run multiple `SQL queries` where the `LIKE` operator contains every element of a list in **Python**.  I have a long list of strings

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3',....]

query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[0]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[0])
query_2 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[1]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
query_3 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[2]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
```

and so on.

How would I run multiple queries simultaneously with the LIKE operator in every query containing a list element? Is it possible to use the `execute` function on multiple queries or can it only work with one? Would I use a for loop?

EDIT: In the previous version of this question, I asked about running **ONE** query with multiple list elements in the `LIKE` operator. I realized that the final query was something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[0]' OR LIKE 'l[1]' OR LIKE 'l[2]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'.
```

That was not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

query = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request like '{}' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format("' or request like '".join(l))

Comment: ServerException: Code: 62.
DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 262131: 'мусорныхсистем' or request like 'играугадай' or request like 'угадайкто' or request like 'покрывало..' or request lik. Max query size exceeded. Stack trace:

Answer (score 0):

It should be work

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3',....]
    
query = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request like {} AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(", ".join(l))
    client.execute(query)
```